# Newbie needs to multiple select of the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a single table with people's info such as

- `ID`
- `Family` (last name)
- `Name` (first name)
- `Status`
- `IDFather`
- `IDMother`

I'd like to bring up the information containing childs' `Name` and `Family`, as well as their parent's `ID`, `Name` and `Family`, but only those records where parents are dead. So far I've done this, but it only selects children who are dead, not parents (status 5 is deceased).

```
select * from A1 where (IDFather IS NOT NULL and IDMother IS NOT NULL) and [Status]   = '5'


Table sample below:
ID Family Name Status IDFather IDMother
001  Watson Jason  1    123      321
002  Smith  Matt   5    333      111
003  Smith  Mike   1    002      NULL
004  Derulo Sam    5    NULL     NULL
005  Pitt   Jenny  1    NULL     004
```

I tried this statement:

```
select * from Table1 where [Status] = '5'
```

I then wrote a select statement in C#

```
select ID,Name,Family from Table1 where IDFather = "value" or IDMother = "value"
```

At the end of the day I need the `Name`, `Family` of the child and `Name` and `Family` of their parents with parents `ID`.

Answer (score 4):

```
select father.id,
        father.family, 
        father.name
        mother.id,
        mother.family, 
        mother.name
        child.id,
        child.family, 
        child.name
 from A1 father, 
      A1 mother, 
      A1 child
where child.IDFather = father.id
and   child.IDMother = child.id
and (father.status = 5 OR mother.status = 5)
```

Replace the OR with AND if you want to retrieve records where both parents are dead

Oh, and if this is a homework assignment, you may want to rewrite my archaic join syntax with the more modern vernacular. I'm stuck in my ways...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * from your_table
WHERE 
    IDFather IN
    (SELECT ID from your_table WHERE Status = 5)
    AND IDMother IN
    (SELECT ID from your_table WHERE Status = 5)
```

If you want also dead people you could try:

```
SELECT * from your_table
WHERE 
    Status = 5
    OR (
    IDFather IN
    (SELECT ID from your_table WHERE Status = 5)
    AND IDMother IN
    (SELECT ID from your_table WHERE Status = 5))
```